# How can i dual boot elementary OS Freya and Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I've never tried dual booting before. It's always been the feature that I've considered meh... Since my sister wants to use windows and I find elementary OS pretty flexible and easy to use with a beautiful interface. I tried to shrink my Disk D Volume to 120GB and then install it on the unallocated space. I'm clearly new to this kind of thing so I probably sound dumb.It just fails. Doesn't even want to start installing. If anyone can tell me what's the problem and how to do it right I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you have. I read at many places including StackOverflow that I need to disable the "Fast Boot (Startup)" and "Hibernate" options in the power options when I'm logged into Windows. I did that, but the problem was not solved. elementary OS was still not able to detect the Windows installation. So here's what I did:

1. While logged into Windows, **disable fast boot and hibernation** in the power settings.
2. Open disk management (you can go there by pressing  keys or just type **disk management** in the start search). Here you need to have a big enough space that is unallocated (shown in black color). If you do not, then **make some space** by deleting and moving partitions. Make sure you don't have too many partitions.
3. Boot with elementary OS live drive and while installing, choose "Do something else", instead of "Erase everything ..."
4. Create **two partitions** from the unallocated empty space that you see (we created this earlier in step 2). The first partition will be of type **"swap"** and about 2-3 GB should do good here. The second partition is your linux partition, which you can set to use all the remaining available space. Set the **mount point as "/"** (root) for the second partition and set it to type **"ext4"**
5. Now continue with the installation, all should work fine. Be careful not to erase a partition with data when making empty space in step 2.

Hope this helps! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 10 already installed, during the installation of elementary OS you can choose for an installation besides Windows 10.

It will let you choose how much space you want for elementary OS and Windows and will shrink the harddisk for you!

Comment: But it doesn't give that option! It doesn't even recognize that another os is on the harddisk!

Comment: Have you tried to boot without UEFI option? Or maybe with UEFI option?
You can switch to UEFI or disable it in your Bios